# React: Confusion with accessing another components state

Tags: reactjs

I'm completely new to React and am a bit confused. I've read around and people say you shouldn't need to access another components state.

So I have two classes: Login.js and InputBox.js (and a few more - shouldn't make a difference in this case).

InputBox is a class that contains a bootstrap Form.Control with an onChange event that will store the inputted value in the state. I made this class so I can quickly reuse the code when creating other forms. Surely Login.js needs to be able to access the state to get this value in order to send a request to my backend? My thought process could be completely wrong.. apologies if so!

**InputBox.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form'
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col'
import FormGroup from 'react-bootstrap/FormGroup'

class InputBox extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    
        this.state = {
             textInput: ""
        }
    }

    changeHandler = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            textInput: event.target.value
        })
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <>
            <FormGroup>
                <Col md={3}>
                    <Form.Label>{this.props.label}</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control type={this.props.type} placeholder={this.props.placeholder} onChange={this.changeHandler} value={this.state.textInput} />
                    <Form.Text className="text-muted">
                        {this.props.description}
                    </Form.Text>
                </Col>
            </FormGroup>

            </>
        )
    }
}

export default InputBox
```

**Login.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import "../css/App.css"
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container'

import FormArea from '../molecule/FormArea';
import InputBox from '../molecule/InputBox';

class Login extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Login">
        <Container fluid>
          <FormArea>

            <InputBox type="text" label="Username" placeholder="Enter username" description="We will never pass your information!" />

            <InputBox type="password" label="Password" placeholder="Enter password" />

          </FormArea>
      </Container>
    </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Login
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you'll be writing a POST request to send login credentials to the backend from the Login component.

I would lift up both state and handler method from the input component into the login component.

Then pass state and handler from Login to Input component via props.

```
class Login extends Component {
    state = {
       username: "",
       password: "",
    }

   changeHandler = (event)  => {
      this.setState({[event.target.field]: event.target.value })
   }
    
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Login">
        <Container fluid>
          <FormArea>

            <InputBox changeHandler={this.changeHandler} value={this.state.username} type="text" label="Username" placeholder="Enter username" description="We will never pass your information!" />

            <InputBox changeHandler={this.changeHandler} value={this.state.password} type="password" label="Password" placeholder="Enter password" />

          </FormArea>
      </Container>
    </div>
    )
  }
}

class InputBox extends Component {
    
    render() {
        return (
            <>
            <FormGroup>
                <Col md={3}>
                    <Form.Label>{this.props.label}</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control type={this.props.type} placeholder={this.props.placeholder} onChange={this.props.changeHandler} value={this.props.value} />
                    <Form.Text className="text-muted">
                        {this.props.description}
                    </Form.Text>
                </Col>
            </FormGroup>

            </>
        )
    }
}
```

In addition, I believe you might also need to have a 'name' prop on your form inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Create the handle input function on your Login

```
function handleInput(someValue){
    setInput(someValue);   //create state for inputs
}
```

When you call the InputBox Component, pass in a prop called inputValue, which will basically handle the input.

```
<InputBox changeHandler={this.changeHandler} value={this.state.username} 
       type="text" label="Username" placeholder="" 
       inputValue={handleInput}
/>
```

On your InputBox Component, call the inputValue props and parse the value of the input in the props function.

```
    changeHandler = (event) => {
        props.inputValue(event.target.value);

        this.setState({
            textInput: event.target.value
        })
    }
```

The value that you've parsed on your InputBox's inputValue prop, can now be accessed in your Login component

Your basically letting your inputBox handle the state of of Login's setInput.

I hope it makes sense